# the Model filed can't named 'model' in peewee?

Tags: peewee

I use peewee-async which is based on peewee to create a Model which has a field named 'model'

```
class Test(peewee.Model):
    model = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        db_table = 'test'
        schema = 'opr'`
```

when I create a object,It happens a error:

```
File "/home/mwh/py3workplace/workplace/ad_tornado/handlers/opr.py", line 78, in post
yield from self.db.create(TaskReqEven,**insert_sql)
TypeError: create() got multiple values for argument 'model'
```

I tried to use other name replace 'model',It submitted correctly to database,so I 
douted if the model name can't name 'model'?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is in some override you've created?  Look at your code. Whatever "db.create()" is doing is the problem.

Comment: model_field = peewee.CharField(db_column='model',max_length=255)  do like this?   It seems to take no effct....